# MappingInstantiationException upon retrieving multi-dim array of doubles from mongo in spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

I am building a spring MVC app with MongoDB. How can I read matrices in spring from mongo? I have a model which persists to mongo just fine using the MongoTemplate class:

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
m.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
m.setValues(values);
mongoTemplate.insert(m, "matrix");
```

The above code works just fine. Values is a double[][] and it is persisted. I am using an extension of the MongoRepository class to make a findAll() call for a list of matrices.

```
public interface MatrixRepository extends MongoRepository<Matrix, String> {

    Matrix findById(String id);
}
```

And in my service class:

```
public List<Matrix> readAll() {
    return matrixRepository.findAll();
}
```

This calling this causes the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [java.lang.Double]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Double.<init>()
    org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.<init>(BeanWrapper.java:105)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper.create(BeanWrapper.java:73)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:239)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:187)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readCollectionOrArray(MappingMongoConverter.java:736)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getValueInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:695)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$2.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:252)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$2.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:242)
    org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:173)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:242)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:187)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:151)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:73)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDbObjectCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:1693)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1444)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1259)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:1248)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:471)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:255)
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.SimpleMongoRepository.findAll(SimpleMongoRepository.java:192)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: What does your `Matrix` class look like?

Answer (score 1):

It happens if your monogo entity class has Double or double fields in spring data mongodb 1.0.0.M5 environment. 
You can fix this by replacing your spring data mongodb with a newer version 1.3.3 RELEASE in your pom.xml